# Modelling an existing database in .NET Core 2.x

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0, ef-core-2.1

I have an existing application.  I am trying to port some pieces over from .NET 4.x over to .NET Core.  I have created a context in my .NET Core app.  I have create a db context via scaffold-dbcontext.  I can run a basic query (hooray).  Life is good.  Now, I want to add in some async queries.  I get the following error:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'The provider for the source IQueryable doesn't implement IDbAsyncQueryProvider. Only providers that implement IDbAsyncQueryProvider can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations. For more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=287068.'

code:

```
var ctx = new GolfGameContext();    
var userId = await (from u in ctx.AspNetUsers where u.Token == UserToken select u.Id).SingleAsync();    
return userId;
```

This error seems strange.  I have created some .NET Core 2.x apps from scratch and everything seems to work properly.  I am able to do async queries with them just fine.  When I look at the error link, I get taken to information about EF 6.x.  I am guessing that there is something that the scaffold-dbcontext puts in the resulting models that cause this problem.  I am also guessing that the code I have created in Core 2.x doesn't contain these same limitations.  Am I on the right track?  Do I need to change something in my context/models to get async to work properly?  All thoughts are welcome.

TIA,

Wally

Comment: I guess, from the error message, that your provider doesn't implement asynchronous operations... What database do you use?

Comment: Can you show us the full `scaffold-dbcontext` command that you used?

Comment: @JohnyL - I am using sql azure from msft.

Comment: @PeterB - I used the basic command from the msft web site:
Scaffold-DbContext "..." Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models

Comment: @PeterB - Is there an option regarding doing something different to get the async support?

Comment: What versions of the NuGet packages do you have installed? Ensure they're consistent.

Comment: thanks @bricelam.  The packages I have should be consistent in the project, at least they appear to be.